# como ordenar según el resultado de una ecuación (división y multiplicación) en php

Tags: php, tablas

Cómo ordeno de mayor a menor según el resultado de la división que tengo en la tabla, el resultado lo da correctamente. Necesito hacer que se ordenen de mayor a menor según el resultado.

Se usa solamente `php` y `html`.

```html
<?php
 $id = "a";
 $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','jg_stats');
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM equipos WHERE grupo = '".$id."'";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
 ?>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <tH colspan="6">
          <center>Grupo A</center>
        </tH>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <tH> equipo</tH>
        <tH>JJ</tH>
        <tH>JG</tH>
        <th>JP</tH>
        <tH>JE</tH>
        <tH translate="no">AVG</tH>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result )){ ?>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row[1]; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row[3]; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row[4]; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row[5]; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row[6]; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo floor((($row[4] / $row[3]) * 1000)); ?>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Tienes que construir el array ANTES de pintar la tabla y los `<td>` y todo eso. Así, calculas la división ANTES y puedes ordenarlos antes de comenzar a pintar.

Answer (score 0):

En `MySql` tienes la función `FLOOR()` para realizar el cálculo directamente desde el motor y lo puedes ordenar de manera descendente con `ORDER BY alias DESC`.

```
SELECT *, FLOOR((campo4 / campo3) * 1000) calculado
FROM equipos 
WHERE grupo = '".$id."'"
ORDER BY calculado DESC
```

Así te llega ordenado para recorrerlo en `PHP` con el ciclo `while`